# Not able to install Magento 2.9 getting an API error message : An error occured when executing th application API

Tags: magento2

FUrther Drill down on the log reveled the below.

> [ERROR] Exception: Missing following extensions: 'zip' in

Need help

Comment: Do you mean 2.2.9?

Comment: Although it will help to install zip on server. Exact steps will differ depending on what you are using to host. Do you know what you are hosting with? For example is it cpanel?